# unable to Include Files php using include

Tags: php, file, include, directory

I have a page called index.php which includes a page new_display.php which again includes two pages i.e. say x.php and y.php

The include is working fine on localhost but not on my hosting! The error i am getting is :-

**Warning: require(/interests/sketching/udis.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hermes/bosweb/web054/b548/ipg.pingcampuscom/mysql/interests/sketching/new_display.php on line 154**

**Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/interests/sketching/udis.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php-5.2.17/lib/php') in /hermes/bosweb/web054/b548/ipg.pingcampuscom/mysql/interests/sketching/new_display.php on line 154**

The Directories are :

**index.php -> localhost/mysql**

new_display.php -> **localhost/mysql/interests/sketching/new_display.php** ( Included in index.php as /interests/sketching/new_display.php )

then in new_display x.php and y.php are included as

**/interests/sketching/x.php**

**/interests/sketching/y.php**

It works all good in localhost but gives error when i publish the pages on the Domain

Does anyone has any idea why isn't this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/` indicates an absolute path, meaning your script is looking in the root of the filesystem for a directory called `interests`.

Instead, try just removing that `/` at the start of your paths, or prepend `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to them.

Comment: can you give me a small example of what $_server['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] works like and how can i use it? please @kolink

Comment: Use `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to see what's in the variable. That should explain it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make

```
require(interests/sketching/udis.php)
```

Without

```
"/"
```

Because you have to point to the same folder ;).